# Javascript to use method accessing different html page data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two HTML pages, showNutrition.html and showMeals.html. On showNutrition.html, I have a button that I want to press to add a row with a user inputted name to the table on showMeals.html. I am unsure how to write the javascript function to access the showMeals.html. This is the code I have so far.

showNutrition.html button:

```
`<a class="topcoat-button center full" onclick="saveMeals()">Save Meal As Favorite</a>`
```

showMeals.html table:

```
<table id = "mealTable" border="1" rules="rows">
      <caption><b>Your Favorite Meals</b></caption>
      <tr>
      <th align="left" width="150">Meal Name</th>
      <td width="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

My current non-working javascript:

```
function saveMeals(){
var mealName = prompt("What would you like to name your meal?");
if (mealName!=null)
{
/*This does not work because document is not referring to showMeals.html, and I don't know how to access a separate page*/
  var table = document.getElementById("mealTable");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = mealName;
  var check = document.createElement('input');
  check.type = 'checkbox';
  cell2.appendChild(check);
 }
}
```

Comment: A JSFiddle would be appreciated.

Comment: @NatZimmermann This problem would be hard to reproduce with a Fiddle. It sounds like he's using frames or multiple windows.

Comment: @acbabis Ah yes I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: I found an example of jquerys $.get method but I am unsure how to use it in my case of altering data on a different page

Comment: Perhaps I would be better suited to just throw the Favorites table on the same page as showNutrition, but have my View Favorites button toggle the table on and off? That way adding to the table would be easy.

Comment: Are you actually using frames?

Answer (score 0):

If showMeals is in an iframe, you get the elements in that document by using

```
document.getElementById('showMeals').contentWindow.document.getElementById('mealTable');
```

where 'showMeals' is the id attribute of the iframe showMeals.html is loaded in.

```
<iframe src='showmeals.html' id='showMeals'></iframe>
```

some browsers may user contentDocument instead of contentWindow. The reference is here
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp